# Random sampling of groups after pandas groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a large dataframe that looks like this:

| Nationality | Sex | Response |
| --- | --- | --- |
| American | Female | I have no need for this product. |
| German | Male | It looks great. |
| Finnish | Female | I would definitely buy one. |

etc.

What I want to do is to randomly select a number of responses from each group so that I can analyse them further.

My groupby function has returned something like this:

```
Nationality Sex
American    Male    567
American    Female  342
German      Male    421
German      Female  234
Finnish     Male    149
Finnish     Female  67
```

etc.

I want to have a new dataframe with 20 random responses of each group. Is that possible using lambda? Because `new_df = df.groupby('Nationality')['Sex'].apply(lambda x: x.sample(20))` doesn't return what I am looking for. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [iterrows](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html) from Pandas you can iterate over DataFrame rows as (index, Series) pairs, and get what you want:

```
new_df = df.groupby(['Nationality', 'Sex'], as_index=False).size()

for _, row in new_df.iterrows():
    print(df[(df.Nationality==row.Nationality)&(df.Sex==row.Sex)].sample(20))
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
df_sample = df.groupby(['Nationality', 'Sex']).sample(20)
```

MVCE:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1':np.random.choice([*'ABC'],100),
                   'Col3':np.arange(100), 
                   'Col2':np.random.randint(1000,5000,100)})

print(df.groupby('Col1').sample(5))
```

Output:

```
   Col1  Col3  Col2
83    A    83  1637
58    A    58  4090
17    A    17  4179
86    A    86  3848
74    A    74  2067
49    B    49  4369
50    B    50  4452
42    B    42  4205
7     B     7  2394
54    B    54  3541
40    C    40  3956
67    C    67  4018
9     C     9  4591
48    C    48  1536
26    C    26  2720
```